# Buttons background turns to blue color (not same as original)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

my problem seems to be easy but I have no idea how to solve it.
I have a few buttons and all of them have a background image. The problem is, all images turns into blue color

It looks like this:

[image]

Original photo:

[image]

Here's a part of my xml code:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/memory_button1"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:maxWidth="30dp"
  android:maxHeight="30dp"
  android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.showTile(1)}"
  android:background="@{viewModel.button001}">
</Button>
```

Icons url:
https://www.flaticon.com/packs/restaurant-225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach to use `ImageView` as button with ripple click effect would be

```
  <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/memory_button1"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:maxWidth="30dp"
       android:maxHeight="30dp"
       android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.showTile(1)}"
       android:src="@{viewModel.button001}"/>
```

Also you can even wrap it in a `CardView`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the only image in your button. you can replace it with `ImageView` so that you can have full control of how the image is being drawn.

```
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/memory_button1"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:maxWidth="30dp"
       android:maxHeight="30dp"
       android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.showTile(1)}"
       android:src="@{viewModel.button001}">
</ImageView>
```

You will option for scale type for `ImageView`'s so that you can render image without stretching it.